# How to tab to an HTML table with inplace edit

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom

I am using YUI3 datatable with inplace edit (own implementation), but the question seems to be relevant for any table with inplace edit.

The question is this. When the user tabs off some input field (s)he is taken to the next focusable element in the tab order. In case of the table being the next in order, the user is taken to the headers, because these contain the sorting buttons. When the last header is left, the focus shifts to the first input field after the table. But, of course, no inplace edit in the table is activated.

I thought to solve it by intercepting the TAB key of the last input before the table (the input would be marked with a special class), activating the inplace edit in the first cell of the table and finally focusing it.

What I dislike about my approach, is that it:

1. Requires me to mark the last input before the table. I must remember it if more inputs are added later.
2. Depends on the collaboration between the last input before the table and the table.

Another solution would be to make the table explore the DOM tab order (using the tabIndex DOM property) in order to locate the last input automatically. But this seems too complex.

Is there a simpler approach, without the described deficiencies?